# Access existing HTML files in a Sitecore installation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore

With virtually any PHP CMS you can easily access the existing files using .htaccess rules, when leaving the rest of the requests handled by the index.php file. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How do I achieve the same in a .NET env, specifically Sitecore? So that I can upload, say, static.html to the root folder and it will be accessible at http://www.example.com/static.html?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be default behavior from Sitecore and should work out of the box. Just try it :)

Comment: Agreed. This comes down to how IIS works, not Sitecore. IIS will try and serve HTML files before sending an incoming request to the .NET/Sitecore stack.

Comment: Great, thanks guys. Can you convert the comment in to an answer so that I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 2):

just put your static.html file in the website folder or any subfolder
it should be fine.

and if you have a multiple website in your sitecore instance,
your html file will be accessible from all website

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of Sitecore to serve real files from the webroot, so you shouldn't have to change anything for it to do this.